# st_intersection and st_intersects are having memory issues

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf

I am working with a dataset of over 25,000,000 points and I want to subset the dataset with respect to a polygon shapefile to only keep the points that are within these polygons. I have used `st_intersection()` from the `sf` package before and I was able to do this. I need to create a new dataset of the subset points to include additional features from the polygons but I don't understand why I can't be able to do this. I keep getting error massages such as `Memory Exhausted` or `cannot allocate vector of size ...`, or most of the time my laptop crashes.

I have increased the memory size with `memory.limit(size=...)`, I have updated R with the latest version and updated all the packages, I have used `st_intersects()`, and I have worked on a faster computer at the office and I'm still having this memory issue. My laptop runs on a 8GB RAM, and the computer at my office is much faster.

I don't understand what is happening because I was able to do this before. Can someone please help with this issue? I don't know what else to do and I need to create this new dataset.

Is there a way for me to add the additional attributes of the polygon shapefiles to the dataset that I already subset before, as another option?

Comment: What do you mean by `to include additional features from the polygon`? Can you add a small example of desired output?

Comment: Adding features from the polygons to points sounds like `st_join()`. Did you try that function? Did you check whether it makes a difference whether you use GEOS (`sf_use_s2(F)`) or S2 (`sf_use_s2(T)`)? You could also loop over the points object, e.g. applying the function to a million points at a time rather than to the full data set at once.

Comment: @agila What I mean is adding attributes from the polygon shapefile like "location name" or "street address" to the point dataset.

Comment: @Chr I used ```st_join()``` to add the "street address" attribute to the points that I originally subset but for some reason it duplicated my points. For example, for a specific place of interest, I subset about 50,000 points and when I used ```st_join()``` to add the "street address" attribute, I got a total 430,000 points. I will try the other two options that you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: @A.Quinones I do not know what your street address data looks like. Points might intersect with multiple observations in the street address data. Note that you can select different types of joins in `st_join()` or select street addresses based on other attributes.